# Is there a recommended way to restart node.js https server without killing node process?

Tags: node.js, ssl, hashicorp-vault

I am retrieving ssl/tls certificate information from a [vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/), which will sometimes be rotated along with my other credentials.

I was looking through node [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) server module documentation along with the tls documentation, but I haven't yet made up my mind on what might be the best approach to tackle the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by modifying [http-shutdown](https://github.com/thedillonb/http-shutdown) while also making judicious use of `setTimeout` to check for new certificate availability in vault.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nodemon` or `pm2` to restart your node server when it crashes or when file changes are detected. Just run the following to install either one:

`npm install -g nodemon` or `npm install -g pm2`

Then start your app like so:

`nodemon app.js` or `pm2 start app.js`

Also look into their documentations, as they offer quite a few options.

Comment: Yeah, that's not really what I'm after. I don't want to have the process crash or bounce. I do use process monitors though already. Thanks though.

Comment: AFAIK there's no easy way to 'hot-swap' code or configurations in node.js without restarting the process. If you're okay with starting a new process then you could just kill the process programatically (`process.exit(1);`) and let your process monitor restart it.

Comment: Well I'm starting to write code to utilize the [stop](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_server_close_callback) method, then creating a new server, just wanted to make sure this was the best way, and looking to see if there was a good example.